# Windows 7 Smooth Scrolling

Tags: scrolling

Is smooth scrolling broken in Windows 7 x64?

It is enabled in *both* **Internet Options** *and* **Performance/Visual effects**

Windows Explorer doesn't even make a pretense at smooth scrolling (only scrolls jerkily lines-at-a-time). Neither do most other apps.

Internet Explorer is the **only** app that actually "smooth-scrolls".

Using Microsoft Comfort Optical Mouse 3000 with Intellipoint driver.

<sub>*Do **not** give an answer "lower the number of lines scrolled at a time", I know about that setting, and it just slows down jerky scrolling, it's not what I'm looking for.*</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the Intellipoint driver at fault. After removing Intellipoint, Windows no longer recognized the fourth and fifth mouse buttons, so I used [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to map them manually.

It's still not perfect "smooth-scrolling," but the acceleration is much more predictable, and Windows Explorer now scrolls consistently line-by-line instead of by random jerks.